# Statistics for IOS app

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, statistics, ios6.1

I have an app uploaded on apple store, I need to check how many % of users using my app have ios5/6/6.1/7 installed. One can check the statistics for Android on Google store, how do we do it for Apple !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to POST `[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion` to a `REST api` of some sort as Apple doesn't supply those statistics

Comment: Yeaah, that i need to incorporate in my code. But this app is currently live. Any tool to get the statistics ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - you'd need your users to update. You can also incorporate something like BugSense which can track those statistics for you (and bugs!)

Comment: Whats BugSense, never heard of it ! Some sort of 3rd party API ?

Comment: Correct-- you can find it at bugsense.com

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question, please feel free to accept at your leisure :)

Comment: There's quite a few tools out there now for this kind of data, I use Flurry, but there are other good tools out there too, I think another is called appcentric... or something...

Answer (score 0):

Though there are tons of analytics libs like Flurry out there it sounds like you're looking for something that might help out with what you have live on the store. If your app has any web page viewing, like a "products" page. You can see the browser/os/device stats by instrumenting the site with google analytics.